# serving clasic .asp pages works on IIS express but fails on production IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, handlers

I'm making a web application with urlrewrites using global.asax, and in some point, i check if the page is a classic .asp page to serve special content or make redirections.

I have the application working on development under IIS Express, but when i move to production server, the application fails, giving me a "500 - interval server error".

I make the checks for the page in global.asax Application_BeginRequest event as normal in this cases, and i have the following in Web.config:

```
  </system.web>
     ...
     <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
        <buildProviders>
          <add extension=".asp"  type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
        </buildProviders>           
     </compilation>
     ...
  </system.web>

  ...

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>      
      <add name="popopopo" path="*.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I repeat, this is working like a charm in IIS Express in development.

The production server is a shared hosting, so i haven't got access to the IIS itself. I make a test calling Page.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_SOFTWARE") to see the server version, and both (local and production) returns "Microsoft-IIS/8.0".

I previously tried to use httphandlesrs inside system.web, but this other configuration is the only one worked for me on local IIS.

Any idea of what can be need to be configurated in addition to this for production server?

Comment: Disable custom error pages for both IIS and ASP.NET so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I have custom errror pages disabled in my app. I can't configure server itself because it's a shared hosting, but it looks like the clasic grey background and red title error page in IIS.

Comment: IIS Express does not have a built-in ASP handler but full IIS might. Thus, you need to talk to the hosting provider to confirm that, and probably use <remove> tag to remove the server level handler for .asp.